# How to get album id and to upload image to fan page album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All available descriptions to upload an image to a fanpage use an album id, but
no one describes the format of the id and how to get it.
Are there examples of php code to get the album id of an album on a fanpage 
and examples to upload an image to that page

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps you will need to build, using the graph api.

1. Get the facebook ID for the page.
2. Get an access_token from the page you want to upload to.
3. Make a form to POST to "https://graph.facebook.com/". $_userID . "/photos?access_token=". $_accessToken

The image will be uploaded to a folder with the same name as you app. So if your app is called "Magic Photo Uploader", the photos will go into a folder called "Magic Photo Uploader Photos"

In my experience you will not need an album ID, I think that documentation is outdated, since for all my apps it makes a album for those app photos and I cannot rename it. But there was once upon a facebook, a REST API that used to let you create and populate albums. Not sure if that is still accessible as a legacy.

Comment: The problem is solved and many applications are working well.

Comment: @Klaus: If this answer helped you solve your problem then the appropriate thing to do is to **accept** the answer by clicking that checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Klaus-DieterBrinkmann you can take a look at an "instruction" explaining how we at Stack Overflow deal with _helpful_ answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235